# vscode golive causes blocking by cors

Tags: spring, cors

I create FE side and go live in visual studio code, BE is created by spring boot.

I tried to fetch data by API from BE side but I got blocked .

```
show-detail.html:1 
 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/get/S1' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Here is the error.
I also have CorsConfig class in spring boot.

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5500")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
```

After this, I still blocked so how can I pass?

Comment: Please edit your question and produce a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example